# Python flask form submit function to background process

Tags: python, multithreading, process, background

I would like to know how can we do the process after the form submit as a background process.

```
from flask import Flask, g, redirect, url_for
@app.route("/form", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
if request.method == 'POST':
    #form processing(This block need to do as background)
    #background must have access to the app.* and g.* variables
    return redirect(url_for('app.form_result'))
g.result['page_title'] = 'Form Input'
g.template = 'form.html'
return 'Done'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions:

First, Use APScheduler (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/APScheduler) and schedule the process as a single job:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def processing_function(app, g):
    pass # Perform your processing here

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.start()
scheduler.add_job(processing_function, app, g)
```

Second, Use Celery (http://www.celeryproject.org/).  Use this if you want to run your background process on a separate server.  I won't provide a code sample here, but you'll need to start a Celery worker, as well as a broker, both separately from your web server.  Then, you can pass jobs back to the worker (with arguments), and have the response sent back.